# JBOSS hang in AIX

Tags: jboss, ldap, aix, freeze

My LDAP Client hangs and the following stack trace is shown

```
 at java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:196(Compiled Code))
 at com/sun/jndi/ldap/Connection.readReply(Connection.java:476)
 at com/sun/jndi/ldap/LdapClient.getSearchReply(LdapClient.java:643)
 at com/sun/jndi/ldap/LdapClient.search(LdapClient.java:566)
 at com/sun/jndi/ldap/LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:1997)
 at com/sun/jndi/ldap/LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1859)
 at com/sun/jndi/ldap/LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1784)
 at com/sun/jndi/toolkit/ctx/ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:398)
 at com/sun/jndi/toolkit/ctx/PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:368)
 at com/sun/jndi/toolkit/ctx/PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:351)
 at javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:278)
```

How to resolve this? Is there any setting that can help?
Unless I restart JBoss, I cannot launch anything on it.

Comment: How often does it happen? Is it a network-related problem? If so, you might want to change the TCP_KEEPALIVE interval from 2 hours to 20 sec. (That's what /usr/bin/no is good for.)

Comment: This happens randomly and works fine for sometime and then hangs abruptly during repeated runs.Let me check this out.Is there a way our application can terminate without causing a hang?

Comment: Then it _might_ be a network-problem. Regarding keepalive see this: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#overview